# Shielding on network cards - why it's used?

Tags: networking, network-adapter, pci-express

I noticed that plenty of enterprise grade network adapters use weird metal "fences" near pci-e connector. I think it's kind of shield isolating NIC from motherboard but to be honest... Why do we need such thing? NICs operate on digital data and don't really seem to be that much vulnerable to electromagnetic noise so what's purpose of those metal fences? I'm talking about piece of metal near the edge of card, like one here:

[image: Network card with shield]

Also some of them are placed a bit above PCB so it makes even less sense to me if it's supposed to be EM shield.

Comment: Just speculating, isn't that to block the adjacent PCI* port, so that you don't plug something that will risk touching that large heatsink?

Comment: It could be to isolate the motherboard from the NIC.

Comment: they raise good points, how do you come to the conclusion that it is used for shielding?

Answer (score 2):

From a mechanical perspective I agree with Nathan. It looks like the intent is to prevent the heatsink from being hit when the card is fitted in a computer or to ensure adequate distance to the next component/chassis for ventilation.

The chip underneath the heatsink is likely to have thermal compound applied and a nudge of the heatsink as it catches another component in the PC would crack the paste bond between heatsink and chip and so cause the chip to run hotter than it normally would.

As mentioned it could also be to indicate minimum spacing to the next PCIe card or chassis for ventilation and heat dissipation. Many cards of this type will be in space restricted 1U chassis and so could be very close to the case, this bracket would give a clear contact to a case being fitted without affecting the heatsink connection to the chip.